# Z3 support of -m option

Tags: z3

On unix I am trying to use AProVE, which uses Z3. I downloaded and built the source (4.1.2; although z3 -version shows 4.2). AProVE uses z3 with the -m option, but 4.2 does not support -m. According to the AProVE developers -m was available in z3 4.0.

How can I get source files for z3 that supports -m? Or, is there a simple fix to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model generation is enabled by default. We don't need to provide option `-m` anymore. 
If you can't change AProVE, you can create a wrapper for Z3 that removes the option `-m` before invoking Z3. Another option is to hack the file `shell\main.cpp` in the Z3 source code.
It contains a function called

```
void parse_cmd_line_args(int argc, char ** argv)
```

To include a dummy `-m` option that doesn't do anything, you just have to include a new `if-statement`.

```
        else if (strcmp(opt_name, "m") == 0) {
            // do nothing
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified main.cpp to ignore the -m option, and AProVE now successfully works with Z3.

Comment: Great! Could you close/accept the answer? In this way, other users know that the issue was solved.